# CI 2.1.1 documentation The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, frameworks

I Have following step by step the documentation in news section. In news, CI can open data from database. in database there are 2 data like this
[Put news data from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cABKc.png)

In there, there is view article link. but after click the link, CI open error 404 like this
 [News Item from View article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce75j.png)

can help me to solve the problem? i'm sorry my english is bad

News_model.php

```html
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->load->database();
 }
        
        public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
        {
            if ($slug === FALSE)
            {
                    $query = $this->db->get('news');
                    return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
}
```

Controller (News.php)

```html
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('news_model');
 }

 public function index()
 {
  $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
                $data['title'] = 'News archive';

 $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
 $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
 $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }

 public function view($slug)
 {
            $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
                
            if (empty($data['news_item']))
            {
                show_404();
            }

 $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

 $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
 $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
 $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }
}
```

Index.php in news View

```html
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

view.php in view

```html
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
```

Comment: check the function called Agung is exist in news controller

Answer (score 0):

You haven't completed the "Routing" section at the end of that [tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/tutorial/news_section.html).

Also, don't start learning with CodeIgniter 2.x - it's no longer supported - go for version 3 instead.